# How to give VM parameter to JBoss from command line?

Tags: parameters, jboss, jvm

I am configuring JaCoCo code coverage tool to work with JBoss. This includes adding the JaCoCo agent as a VM parameter to JBoss. I have got it to work by adding the parameter to JAVA_OPTS straight in the JBoss run.config scripts, but because this needs to be quite dynamic, I would need to give the VM parameter at command line (executed by Jenkins). How do I do this? I know system properties can be given using the "D" before the key.

Also, is it possible to add the agent to the run.config file, and then pass a custom property to it? So I would add this to the run.config file:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -javaagent:/home/installations/jacoco/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=$path/jacoco.exec"
```

And then I would start JBoss like this:

```
./run.sh -Dpath=/home/workspace/jacoco
```

Does something like this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since run.sh itself is a shell script file, which means it accepts parameters you pass in. Or, you can write another shell script to wrap up the run.sh, then you can handle the parameters you want in this outer script file and don't need to taint the original run.sh, which offers more portability.